I get this warning for batch files I created, & very safe exe's: "The Publisher could not be verified. Are you sure you want to run this software"?"
I get this warning for batch files I created, & very safe .exe files:

"The Publisher could not be verified. Are you sure you want to run
this software?"

The same warning pops up when I select "Edit" after I have right-clicked on a ".CMD" file (which I coded/created using a text editor, EditPad Pro) in Windows Explorer.
I think that it is not normal Windows behavior to this warning when I am opening a ".CMD" file with a text editor.
Is this a sign that my Windows security is corrupt?
If yes, can I fix it short of reinstalling Windows?
Any suggestions about how to learn how to get rid of these security problems would be much appreciated.
